# Snort Message - WARNING: No preprocessors configured for policy 0

Tags: linux, snort

I have installed and configured snort 2.9.7.2 and it is running without a problem. However, my question is: what does the following warning mean?

> "No preprocessors configured for policy 0"

This message shows when I run the command:

```
snort -v
```

Comment: how you solved your problem?

Answer (score 10):

This message indicates that no snort preprocessor is loaded. In order to get rid of this warning, please use the following command:

```
snort -v -c /etc/snort/snort.conf
```

Please make sure that the configuration file `/etc/snort/snort.conf` is present and preprocessors are enabled in the configuration file.

Comment: After doing this I get this message

ERROR: ../rules/app-detect.rules(33) Unknown ClassType: web-application-attack
Fatal Error, Quitting..

Comment: Anyone could be forgiven for thinking that path would be loaded by default when omitted.

Comment: In 2019, Snort seems to install incorrectly on Windows 10. I get various error messages trying to follow the documentation examples. One message includes Linux pathnames, which don't exist on Windows. There is no point in including details here if Snort is no longer a viable tool or is not really supported for Windows. Can Snort be used on a Linux server to reduce the load caused by unauthorized website and email activity? I was trying it out on Windows to evaluate it for use on my standard hosted websites and email.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error:

```
No preprocessors configured for policy 0
```

That was because I forgot to unpack all the rules into the proper folders. After unpacking the rules, the error went away.

Answer (score 0):

Check if it is enabled and see if it has any `sid` or `msg` with:

```
snort -A console -c /etc/snort/snort.conf
```

And check if any of the preprocessors are sending alerts if not you should recompile it.

Answer (score 0):

You must enable the snort preprocessors:

```
snort -v -c /etc/snort/snort.conf
```

Make sure `snort.conf` has all your preprocessors enabled.